# Get data through Amazon MWS API

Tags: crystal-reports

I have downloaded SAP crystal report and I would like to know can I get data in my report through an API? I want to get data through Amazon MWS API. Please advise is it possible and is there any documentation.

EDIT: Basically I am trying to use the XML and Web Services item of database expert pop up in crystal reports 2013. Now as you know it expects either a XML url or a web service data source. I need to get data from amazon MWS API, so not sure how to use it here. Also since I am new to crystal reports so for better understanding the concepts I am testing/trying both methods to make it work. I have even followed this tutorial - http://trustedbi.com/2009/05/19/cr-webservice/ but this does not work - it is not populating the method,port and service. I have even created a test xml file from here(http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_usedfor.asp) and saved it locally on my pc and gave that URL but now the error is "Logon failed: schema not defined". My first step is to try it with a simple solution to see how crystal reports work and then figure out how can I use the MWS API.

Comment: Can you provide some details?  Is the error happening with crystal or with Amazon MWS?

Comment: @ScottG I have edited the question for more details.

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to attempt your connection? I'm not sure there is a way for you to pull data directly from Amazon MWS to Crystal Reports, _but_ you may be able to pull the data to an intermediary. C# would be your best bet as it is still in the .NET family. See: https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/sellers/sellers/v20110701/cSharp.html/182-8620814-8585016